# Fatal error when accessing magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, fatal-error

I have Magento 1.9, If i try to access magento admin area by just putting the

URL: www.domain.com/admin

then i dont see login area but i just see this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in /home/themename/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php on line 52
```

Do you know the fix of this?

Comment: check that file, comment out line 52 (if possible) and try reloading again

Comment: @StevenJ I have commented out but didnt solve the issue

Comment: If it's a core file, you could download an archive of your version of magento, or the latest patched version of that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by downloading 1.9.0.1 from magento website and just replaced core folder from newly downloaded files to my website. And it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please remove following directory from your site

var/session,
var/cache

And Try again with admin URL.

Comment: I deleted both cache and session folder but i am still finding same error